# Post to a forum or blog via PHP

Tags: php

This is a random question but, Is it possible to make a PHP script (or another web based language) to login to a forum or a wordpress blog and make a post there? I would like to login to my own account on various forums, and post the same update to each one.

Obviously if it's not possible then oh well, but I just had to ask.

Thanks!

Comment: p.s. 6 questions asked, no answers accepted. Lame.

Comment: No spam bots xD. And sorry, just accepted your answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's entirely possible with stuff like cURL.

No, the forums you're doing this to probably won't like it, and they may have captchas or other things in place to prevent it.

Comment: Hmm, and if they have no Captchas? xD

Comment: Then you'd look into cURL. Captchas aren't the only method, and if you're going to use this to spam, expect them to block you eventually. In short, don't be a dick.

Comment: No, I'm a developer and want to maintain updates on the forums without copy and pasting. That's all, thanks for letting me know about cURL.

Comment: If you're the developer, just add directly via the WordPress API or the database. Much easier.